# Return first row that starts with a certain string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to create a method that returns the first row that starts with "Bob". I think I have it down, but it doesn't seem to print anything.

```
public class apples {

    public static void firstBob(String [][] data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
                if ("Bob".equals(data[i])) {
                    System.out.print(data[i][j]);
                    break;

                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        String [] [] order;
        order = new String [5][5];

        order[0][0] = new String("TV");
        order[0][1] = new String("Radio");
        order[0][2] = new String("Telephone");
        order[1][0] = new String("Bob");
        order[1][1] = new String("Table");
        order[1][2] = new String("Lamp");

        firstBob(order);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be

```
if ("Bob".equals(data[i][j]))
```

You are comparing a string to an array of strings, not an individual string.

A good IDE should pick up on a suspicious call like that.

Also, there is never any reason to write `new String`. You can just do

```
order[0][2] = "Telephone";
```